# jQuery: .filter() returns fewer elements than expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using PHP and an ajax command to take the entire HTML contents of an external web page (via the PHP `file_get_contents()` command) and passing that HTML into a javascript variable.
With the HTML contents in that variable, I am now trying to select & extract certain elements within that variable.
I tried using the `.filter()` function e.g.

```
 $(myHTML).filter('#someID').doStuff();
```

but the `.filter()` command does not seem to accurately filter my selection.

It works in some cases

```
$(myHTML).filter('title').text();
```

yet it does not appear to work when trying to select multiple elements. 
For example, if I try to get a count of all the `<div>` or `<a>` tags, I keep getting zero

```
alert($(myHTML).filter('a').length)
```

even though there are 75 `<a>` tags in this example.

The same happens when trying to get a count of all the `<div>` tags: the above code just returns zero.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: it was hard to read your question so I reformatted it 8 ^ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter will only return the filtered top-level elements, won't traverse children. Use find() instead.

Comment: Very common issue for new jQuery coders, the differences between [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Comment: @Orbling: thanks for the links, I'm just feeding my SO obsession on the bus from my phone and it's not easy to put extra features in on a touch screen.:)

Comment: Aye, definitely fiddly - most people seem to have trouble providing links in general.  Probably because it slows you down and people end up posting before you.